# Running month logic in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two column col_a and col_b. I should have a value to it like in the below image. How can we get this.

[image]

Comment: would you really explain the question properly. You haven't specified any relevent information.

Comment: I need to have the data in the table how it is in the image. But it should be dynamic. if i am running it now it should have the data till Nov.

Comment: No not a image.. For example I showed in image how the should data look in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @month = 3;
select  t.month, s.month from
(
select 1 mns, 'Jan' month union select 2,'Feb' union select 3,'Mar' union
select 4,'Apr' union select 5,'May' union select 6,'Jun'  union
select 7,'Jul' union select 7,'Aug' union select 9,'Sep'  union
select 10,'Oct' union select 11,'Nov' union select 12,'Dec'
) s
,
(
select 1 mnt, 'Jan' month union select 2,'Feb' union select 3,'Mar' union
select 4,'Apr' union select 5,'May' union select 6,'Jun'  union
select 7,'Jul' union select 7,'Aug' union select 9,'Sep'  union
select 10,'Oct' union select 11,'Nov' union select 12,'Dec'
) t
where t.mnt <= s.mns    and t.mnt <= @month
```